# Remove files under AppData that my app has downloaded in Install4J

Tags: install4j

I have an Install4J project where the application installed downloads content to:

```
${installer:sys.userHome}\MyApplication
```

The installer does not copy any files to this location, so it is not part of any file sets etc.

I have tried to add an action in the uninstaller using "Delete files and directories", and copied "`${installer:sys.userHome}\MyApplication`" to "Files and directories"

However, it doesn't seem to delete the folder.

Any pointers on what I am missing?

Edit:

Here is the uninstall log regarding the delete action:

I found this in the uninstall log regarding the delete action:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen [ID 23]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallWelcomeScreen [ID 24]: Show screen
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallWelcomeScreen [ID 24]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallationScreen [ID 27]: Show screen
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 869]: Execute action
       Property directoryFilter: null
       Property fileFilter: null
       Property files: [C:\Users\nim99\AppData\Local\Atlas]
       Property filesRoot: null
       Property backupForRollback: true
       Property recursive: false
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property showProgress: false
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallationScreen [ID 27]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallSuccessScreen [ID 30]: Show screen
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallSuccessScreen [ID 30]: command: finish
       cleaning up
       Finished at 2022-10-04 16:20:25
```

The "Property files: " seem to be ok. This is where my application downloads content to. It does download to sub-folders though:

I looked at the Delete Action and i have the "Recursive" checkbox checked. But the log seems to indicate that recursive is set to false.

```
Property recursive: false
```

[image]

Edit 2:

**I changed the order of the uninstallation actions and now it seems to work!
I had the Uninstall files action first and the Delete files action after that.
With the Delete files action first, it seems to have fixed the problem.**

Comment: Please start the uninstaller from the command line with the argument `-Dinstall4j.log=<path to log file.txt>` and share the output for the "Delete files and directories" action.